# Get all text from online text file and show it all in a TextView

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I want to get all the text from a webpage and save it to a String array/list and then print it in a View/Activity..

Let's say I have URL `www.my.url/html.php` and on that page is this:

> Paul
>
> Caroline
>
> Steve'
>
> ...
>
> ...

And now I want them to be written in the same position in an View/Activity.

I have this simple Activity:

```
public class PlayerListActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playerlist);
    }
}
```

And this XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#121E26"
    tools:context="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame,ContentDescription,HardcodedText,SpUsage,TextViewEdits,Deprecated,SmallSp" >

</FrameLayout>
```

[This](http://s13.postimg.org/iripxf91j/image.png) is what I want it to look like. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I think it might help your description if you explained how what you want is different from using a WebView

Comment: make an edit and I'll take a look if it's allright

Answer (score 0):

if it is simple html data you may download whole HTML. also put `TextView` inside FrameLayout and use

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringWithHtml));
```

[doc of method here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

note that not all HTML tags are supported, unofficial list [HERE](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Comment: this is making my program crash

Comment: `stringWithHtml`, not `stringWithUrl`

Comment: well I need it directly from a website

Comment: so use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and method `loadUrl(String url)`